# R: save vector of text values into .txt files (each element of vector to seperate .txt file)

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a vector, where each values is a text value. To make it simple let's assume its:  `c('a','b','c','d')`
I managed only to save it as one big file:

```
write.table(myVector,"textFile.txt",sep="\t",row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

How could I save each element to a separate file for example 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
myVector <- c('a','b','c','d')

lapply(myVector, function(x) write.table(x, paste0(match(x, myVector), ".txt"), sep="\t",row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote = FALSE))
```